# Parsing JSON list with Python

Tags: python, json, python-requests

I cannot seem to locate my exact case and since I'm a complete noob when it comes to Python. I'm querying a AV scanner for a list of the engines. I need to count the "active" engines so I can use the value later in the code to do some math. Here is the code:

```
import requests
EngineStat = 0 
requests.get("http://metascan.company.com:8008/metascan_rest/stat/engines",)
msavtotal=0
for key in EngineStat:
s = EngineStat[key]
    if key['active']:
        msavtotal += 1
```

Here is the response JSON (just a snip):

```
[
    {
"def_time": "12/02/2015 12:00:00 AM",
"active": true,
"eng_name": "Agnitum scan engine",
"eng_type": "Bundled engine",
"eng_ver": "5.5.1.3"
   },
{
"def_time": "12/02/2015 12:00:00 AM",
"active": true,
"eng_name": "Ahnlab scan engine",
"eng_type": "Bundled engine",
"eng_ver": "3.5.5.1 (13155)"
},
{
"def_time": "12/01/2015 12:00:00 AM",
"active": true,
"eng_name": "AVG scan engine",
"eng_type": "Bundled engine",
"eng_ver": "4213.4159"
```

What I'm looking to do is loop and count the instances when `"active" = "true"`.

When I try to set `s` to `EngineStat[key]` I get an error. This seems like it should be something pretty simple so I'm sure it's just my inexperience. Can anyone lend me a hand?

Comment: you are not pulling the content from the request and not converting it from string to a dict, which you'd do using module `json`

Comment: How come you're not setting `EngineStat` to anything after you set it to `0`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like:

```
import requests

r = requests.get("http://metascan.company.com:8008/metascan_rest/stat/engines")

msavtotal=0
for item in r.json():
    if item['active']:
        msavtotal += 1
```

Comment: MUCH THANKS. This was the ticket. Thank you for your help.